# how to filter lotus notes email to show only calendar invite

Tags: search, filter, gmail, lotus-notes

From a personal point of view, I use Gmail.

I find web based email easy to access, but most of all I use gmail for 1) space, 2) search and filter 3) organisation abilities (labels aka tags) etc.

In lotus notes I frequently get a few hundred email at a time, and I struggle to find the emails where I have been invited to a meeting or where a meeting I am attending has been updated, cancelled or rescheduled.

Why do I even want to find the emails notifying me of calendar invites? Why don't I just use the calendar?

I don't just use the calendar because whenever I right click and select accept it says "you must accept the first version of this invitation (which is somewhere in my email).

Hence my problem.

**Does anyone know how to filter (I think of Gmail search operations like from: to: date:) calendar invites from lotus notes?**

I want to show:

> > Calendar invites I have not accepted?
> >
> > calendar invites which have had description updated
> >
> > calendar invites rescheduled
> >
> > calendar invites which have been cancelled

All the above currently get lost in my normal mail.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the miniview in Calendar (left lower corner), it shows all the documents you are interested in. Or you create a new view with the selection formula:

```
Select Form = "Notice"
```

This view will show all notices.

If your database has a fulltext, then you can open the searchbar and use the query

```
[Form] = Notice
```

Or

```
FIELD Form = Notice
```

To find the corresponding entries.

Comment: There is also a setting to not show invitations in the mailbox after they have been accepted.